# About function of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Proof f(x,y)=$\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2},$when $x^2+y^2\ne 0$

f(x,y)=0,when $x^2+y^2=0$
is Continuity on (0,0) on half-line x=$t \cos\theta,y=t\sin\theta ,0\le t\le+\propto$

My attempt ：

f(0,y)=0,f(x,0)=0, so it’s continuity on x-axis,y-axis,

let k=$\tan \theta$ ,then f=$\frac{kx^3}{x^4+k^2x^2}$
= $\frac{kx}{x^2+k^2}$
$lim_{k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k \ne 0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{kx}{x^2+k^2}=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{kx}{x^2+k^2}=0$

Now, let's consider the $x$-axis, that is when $y=0$ and along that line, $f(x,y)=0$ .

Hence, it is continuouson those half-lines.

Comment: So I almost right?

Comment: is there any reason that stop you from taking the limit?

Comment: Seems like no reason ...thanks

Comment: But can is proper I use k to replace $\theta$

Comment: What about y-axis

Comment: give it a try, what are the $x$-values along the $y$-axis? what  function value does it take along the half lines.

Comment: x is 0,and f is 0,f is continuity on this half lines , so my analysis is right?

Comment: yes, $x=0$ and the function value is $0$ along it hence it is continuous on those two half lines as well.

Comment: then I proof all the half line is continuity